# Avoid to add namespaces into XML (java)

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmlserializer, output-formatting

After make changes inside XML file I want to save my result. I'm using below code:

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
    new File("C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\abc.xml")
);
OutputFormat outputFormat = new OutputFormat(doc, "UTF-8", true);
outputFormat.setOmitComments(true);
outputFormat.setLineWidth(0);

XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(outputStream, outputFormat);
serializer.serialize(doc);
outputStream.close();
```

But into my XML is added line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

How to remove it or avoid to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Below line need to be added:

```
outputFormat.setOmitXMLDeclaration(true);
```

And works perfect!